# Can a Java 9+ project use a separate source module in Java 8, untouched?

Tags: java, maven, java-8, java-9

I have a project, with Maven and Java 11, which use an external
library written in Java 8. It works fine as long as the library is
imported as a Jar file. I'm using IntelliJ, but I'm looking for
answers that are valid for Eclipse as well.

I have also cloned the external repository from GitHub, and want to
use it in source form in my project. One goal is to make improvements
to the external library, and be able to send pull requests on it to
GitHub. But first I want calls from my project to the library to work
without changing anything in the library source code.

However, the class in my project that imports classes from the
external library cannot do that.

In pom.xml, I've tried with

```xml
    <modules>
        <module>../path/to/external-libary</module>
    </modules>
```

and it seems to have some effect, but still the imports don't work.

When the library is used as a Jar, this dependency works:

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.goxr3plus</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-stream-player</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I suspect that I must do something in either module-info.java or in
 pom.xml, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: When you say a `Java11` class in your project cannot import `Java8` classes from the external project, what does that mean? Does the `mvn` build fail? Does it fail with errors in some other way? And the `Java8` jar file file scenario that works in `IntelliJ`, does that mean  the `Java11` imports work correctly?

Comment: @SeanMickey: In IntelliJ, the text of the package+class that I want to import is red or grey; the class names and method names further down in the file are red as a consequence. I run by clicking the green triangle in IntelliJ; that will not work in this case. I don't use maven directly.
Importing the Java8 lib as a jar from Java11 works correctly.

Comment: What Java version is mentioned in the external project pom?

Comment: @Rohit: The external project uses version1.8.

Comment: Perhaps you can share the project structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the external library should be seen as an **automatic module** (being referenced via 'requires' in your module-info, rather than being pulled in on the classpath), then the dependency *must* point to a **jar file**, because automatic modules are defined only for jar files.

Eclipse slightly bends the limit by recognizing also projects on the module path as automatic modules, which still requires additional steps when launching, because the Java runtime will not accept a folder of class files as an automatic module.